# how to write insertinto command in hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I want to write the below InsertInto query in Hibernate Criteria. 
Any Suggestions
 ..
thanks for help

```
        sql = "insert into selectedresumes  values('" + companyId + "','"
        + resumeId + "','" + resumeStatusId + "','" + jobId + "')";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, You can't do it.

According to Hibernate documentation

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch-direct

> Only the INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...
>   form is supported; not the INSERT INTO
>   ... VALUES ... form.

So you just need to create Object and save it using Hibernate and it should look something like that

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
Resume selectedresumes  = new Resume();
//set all resume values
session.save(selectedresumes);
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: thanks for your help , i am doing this same thing but at this line   tx.commit();    it throws   exception      org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update                                                   any idea what the reason.   thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should map your query fileds with pojo class not with SQL or MySQL data base tables.

Like below Employee pojo object has two fields empNo, empName to insert write like below.
Query query = session.createQuery("insert into Employee(empNo, empName)");

int result = query.executeUpdate();

refer this example

http://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-insert-query-tutorial/